# django if value equals enum show field

Tags: python, django

For my django project I try to show a button if a field is equal to an enum value.
I loop over lights and based on the state I want to show a button.

My enum:

```
class DeviceState(Enum):
    UNKNOWN = 1
    STAND_BY = 2
    ON = 3
    OFF = 4
```

My light:

```
class Light:

    def __init__(self, id, name, state: DeviceState = DeviceState.UNKNOWN):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.state: DeviceState = state
```

My relevant template part:

```
{% for light in lights %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ light.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ light.state }}</td>
            <td>
                {% if light.state == 3 %}
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark">Lights off</button><
                {% endif %}
                {% if light.state == "DeviceState.OFF" %}
                   <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Lights on</button>
                {% endif %}

            </td>
          </tr>
      {% endfor %}
```

I tried multiple variations of:

```
{% if light.state == 3 %}
```

e.g.

```
== "3"
== DeviceState.OFF
== 3
== "DeviceState.OFF"
== "OFF"
```

Of which none seem to work.

How should I hide/show elements if a properties value equals a specific enum value?

*note ( i know I can use en elif instead of two else, but just for testing im trying to focus on getting one working.*

Comment: try `light.state.value == 3`

Comment: I believe using `DeviceState.ON` should work without accessing the enum's `value` if you pass `DeviceState` to the context (and give it that name), but I'm not 100% sure

Comment: @EDG956 that .value comment works, but why? in the lines above  <td>{{ light.state }}</td> the output is  <td>DeviceState.ON</td> so why does the compare fail than?

Comment: Because in order to render the value, the template engine calls `str` or `repr` on the enum, but that doesn't happen for comparisons. In python, you're doing `DeviceType.ON.__eq__("DeviceType.ON")`.

Comment: @EDG956 If you can post it as an answer  i can close the question

Comment: Answer submitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to render the value, the template engine calls `str` or `repr` on the enum, but that doesn't happen for comparisons.

The python equivalent to what's going on is `DeviceType.ON.__eq__("DeviceType.ON")`. To do a proper comparation you should access the enum's value like this: `light.state.value == 3` (equivalent to `(3).__eq__(3)`).

If you want to do the `light.state == DeviceType.ON` expression, you should pass the `DeviceType` enum class as part of the context of the template as `{..., "DeviceType": DeviceType}`.